# How do i convert a double into an int when converting minutes to seconds in java

Tags: java

Trying to convert minutes to seconds with the starting data being a double,

so for example 33.51 seconds (33 mins 51 seconds)
How to convert that to an int when converting to seconeds only
My code for now would accept it if there was no double point to begin with, so i only used ints only
and it seems to work, but when i have that double in there it doesnt, is therre a better approach to it .

Heres my code for now

```
public class Runner {
    //fields setting up the variables
    String MembershipID;
    String name;
    int time ;
    //constructor1 filling in the details
    public Runner(String Mem, String na, int ti) {
        MembershipID = Mem;
        name = na; //This
        time = ti;


    }

    public String getMembershipID() {
        return MembershipID;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }    //setting it up for the main method from the constructor fields above

    public int getTime() {
       int mins = time *60;
   


        return mins;
    }

   



    public static void main(String[] args) { //initializing the membership name and time,
        Runner a = new Runner("RF23", "George Formsby", 33);  //Creating a new instance of 
Runner, filling out the details from the sample data provided.
        Runner b = new Runner("RG89", "Neil Innes", 32);
        Runner c = new Runner("ST200", "Sandy Denny", 30); // With mem and na being 
represented from my constructor
        System.out.println("MembershipID is: " + a.getMembershipID());
        System.out.println("Name is: " + a.getName());
        System.out.println("Time in seconds: " + a.getTime());
        System.out.println("MembershipID is: " + b.getMembershipID());
        System.out.println("Name is: " + b.getName());
        System.out.println("Time is: " + b.getTime());
        System.out.println("MembershipID is: " + c.getMembershipID());
        System.out.println("Name is: " + c.getName());
        System.out.println("Time is: " + c.getTime());


    }








    }
```

Comment: Are you **sure** that `33.51` should be 33 minutes and 51 seconds? What would `33.70` be in this case?

Comment: `33.51` should be like 33 minutes and 30.6 seconds.

Comment: I'm sorry if i got your question wrong, but couldnt you just calculate all of this with 33.51 % 1 being the seconds and Math.round(33.51/1) being the minutes? Granted, of course, 33.51 are not supposed to be 33 min and 30 sec

Comment: bad idea to use a double for decimal arithmetic.  You can represent using an int as hours*100+minutes, and then convert back

Comment: This looks like using the wrong data type for the job. 33 minutes and 51 seconds should never be represented by the double `33.51`. You could use `Duration`, but if you want to stick to an `int`, it should represent the number of seconds. In your example it would be *2031* (*33 * 60 + 51*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like simple enough math.

### Convert minutes + seconds to just seconds

```
int minutes = ...;
int seconds = ...;
int totalSeconds = minutes * 60 + seconds;
```

### Convert minutes (as a double) to seconds

```
double time = 12.33;
int seconds = (int) (0.5 + time * 60);
```

Explanation: when rounding to an `int`, java lops off the decimal parts. We want to round to the nearest second, which can be trivially accomplished (for positive numbers!) by adding 0.5 to it and *then* casting to `int`.

NB: See note below!

### Convert seconds (as int) to minutes (as double)

```
int totalSeconds = ....;
double time = time / 60.0;
```

Explanation: In java, The syntactic construct `x / y` is considered to be 'integer division' if `x` and `y` are both integral data types (`byte`, `short`, `int`, `long`, or `char`). It is considered 'floating point division' if either x or y is a floating point type (`float` or `double`). integer division will lop off the decimal digits (so, it rounds down for positive results, and rounds up for negative results). Thus, `90 / 2`, for example, resolves to `1`. Not `1.5`. On the other hand, `90 / 2.0` resolves to `1.5`, because at least one of the two numbers is a double (`2.0` is a double constant, `2` is an int constant). Hence why we divide by `60.0` and not `60`.

NB: Important thing to think about: **PRECISION**.

Computers aren't magical, and `double` is precisely defined as consisting of exactly 64 bits.

You can't store one of an infinite sequence of options in a finite storage space, so, **computers cannot store numbers perfectly**. A 64-bit storage space has the ability to give you at most `2^64` different 'options'. If the storage space is storing a number, that means there are at most `2^64` numbers it could possibly store there, **and all other numbers therefore simply cannot be represented by it**. Somebody needs to go out and define which numbers are 'blessed' - capable of being stored. Then someone needs to define what happens if you attempt to store a non-blessed number in them.

For the integer data types, this is easy: `int` (32-bit) can store 2^32 numbers. Which numbers are blessed? Simply `-2^31` to `+2^31 -1`. When you attempt to store something above or below it, the numbers just loop around:

```
int reallyLarge = Integer.MAX_VALUE; // this is 2^31-1.
int surelyThisIsEvenLarger = reallyLarge + 1;
```

Actually, `surelyThisIsEvenLarger` is negative number instead. It looped around.

For `double` and `float` it is *way more complicated*. Even between just `0` and `1` there are infinite numbers! The blessed numbers are chosen by more or less throwing darts at the numberline, focusing about half the darts close to `1.0`, with fewer and fewer darts hitting the number line as you move away from 1.0. Eventually, at around `2^52`, the 'distance' between any 2 darts is higher than `1.0`, even.

It's a bit like how we humans do it: We cannot 'represent' 1 divided by 3, at all. `0.333333....` it never ends.

To make matters worse, computers count in binary and not decimal. So, where we humans can e.g. do '1 divided by 10' (that's `0.1`, so it is a blessed number in the system of 'a human writes it down in decimal on a bit of paper that has room for about 10 digits'), **computers cannot do that, either**.

Thus, most of the 'take these number of seconds and turn them into a double' values, **are not actually blessed**, so it is important to realize what happens when you try to make a double that isn't blessed: The computer will round it off to the closest blessed number. You can't ask for the error (the amount it rounded by), or ask it not to do this; not with `double`, anyway.

If you do enough back-and-forth math on them, those errors compound and eventually will be flat out wrong. That's one of the many reasons why you should most definitely **never, ever** use `double` to store money values. For race monitoring you're running into a similar situation here, best not to use them. Better to pick an atomic unit and store in those. For example, why not store in millis? The current record for fastest mile is 3:43.13. In 'millis', that becomes `long fastestMile = 223130;` - no need to involve those nasty doubles with their bizarro rounding behaviours.